# PostgreSQL parameterized query in Spring repository

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

I am using Spring framework and PostgreSQL database .In the following query I want to select those rows which have product name matched by the parameter `keyword' When I run the following query it gives me the following error

Does anybody tell me how to write right query ?

**Query:**

```
@Query(value="Select pp from product_photo pp join products p ON pp.product_id=p.id Where p.name ~* ?Keyword",nativeQuery = true)
    List<ProductPhoto> trail(@Param("keyword")String Keyword);
```

**API:**

http://localhost:8080/productPhotos/search/trail?keyword=Bottles

**Error:**

```
could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

**Product Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="products")
public class Product implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_PRODUCTS", sequenceName="PRODUCTS_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_PRODUCTS")
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="NAME", nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name="DESCRIPTION",length=1000)
    private String description;

    @Column(name="PRICE", nullable=false)
    private Double price;

    private String SKU;

    private String supplierCode;

    private String readerOfferCode;

    private float productWeight;

    private Boolean statusEnabled=true;

    private float quantity;

    public String barcode;

    private boolean featuredProduct;

    private Double meanRating;

    private Double discountedPrice;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private stockStatus stockStatus;

    @ManyToOne 
    private Supplier supplier;

    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private ProductCategory productCategory;

    @ManyToOne
    private ProductDepartment productDepartment;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="product",targetEntity=ProductPhoto.class,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<ProductPhoto> pictures;
    ..// Getters and setters 
    }
```

**ProductPhoto Entity**

```
@Entity
public class ProductPhoto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        //@JsonIgnore
        @ManyToOne 
        private Product product;

        private String path;

        private Boolean primaryPhoto=false;

        @Column( nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date uploadDate ;
        //..getters and setters }
```

Comment: can you show us your entities please?

Comment: @YCF_L Check edited question

Comment: @ScaryWombat LIKE in PostgreSQL is case sensitive , and I want to match case insensitive keyword  , That's why I used this

Comment: try to use `@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="id") private Product product;`

Comment: @YCF_L I run the following query from the database and it runs fine so I don't think so it is an `id` issue.. What do you think?
Select pp
from product_photo pp 
join products p ON
pp.product_id=p.id 
Where p.status_enabled='true' 
AND pp.primary_photo='true' 
AND (p.name ~* 'bottles');

Comment: please change `?keyword` to `:keyword` or `?1`, i don't see before something like `?NameOfKeyWord`

Comment: " LIKE in PostgreSQL is case sensitive , and I want to match case insensitive keyword , That's why I used this " To answer this concern use something like this for case insensitivity : `Select pp from product_photo pp join products p ON pp.product_id=p.id Where UPPER(p.name) LIKE UPPER('%yourkeyword%')`

Comment: @ScaryWombat The OP use `nativeQuery = true` so it's mean he/she can use `~`

Comment: @YCF_L Sorry I missed `nativeQuery = true`

Comment: @HirenPandit Now When I run the query It gives following error 
`Parameter with that position [1] did not exist; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: try to use `p.name ~ :keyword`

Comment: `LIKE` is of course case sensitive, however `ILIKE` isn't.

Comment: the question is what did you mean by `p.name ~* ?Keyword`, what you want to match?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't an issue with the paramname being `keyword` and in the query you're using capitalized `Keyword`?

Comment: The follwoing query runs perfectly.. Thanks everyone for your Help 
Especially @HirenPandit

`@Query("Select pp from ProductPhoto pp join pp.product p where pp.product.id=p.id AND p.statusEnabled='true' AND pp.primaryPhoto='true' AND (UPPER(p.name) LIKE UPPER(%:keyword%) or p.description LIKE %:keyword%)")`

Comment: You should really use `ILIKE` instead of `LIKE` with `UPPER`.

Comment: @Kayaman Sure I will try this too

Comment: There's no "try". `LIKE` is the case sensitive comparison, `ILIKE` is the case insensitive comparison. Using `UPPER` is just a sign of a bad programmer who doesn't understand what he's doing with the database.

Comment: @Kayaman I Tried but it gives me an error

`@Query(value="Select pp from product_photo pp join products p ON pp.product_id=p.id Where p.status_enabled='true' AND pp.primary_photo='true' AND p.name ILIKE :%Keyword%)",nativeQuery = true)`
Error: No parameter binding found for name keyword!

Comment: That's because you wrote the parameter name in uppercase again `Keyword` is not `keyword`. You didn't think I was talking about the case of the parameter name, did you? Also, you put the semicolon on the wrong side of the `%`. Oh come on, are you writing this blind or something?

Comment: @Kayaman I wrote Keyword with uppercase because I took parameter name in Upper case... Oh come on , Are you reading this blind or something?

Comment: Your code has `@Param("keyword")` which is lowercase. And what about the `:%` part? In your working code you're using `%:` so why did you change it all of a suddenly? Pay a little attention to what you write.

Comment: @Kayaman O M G seriously? I Don't know why you are so aggressive ? 
This is JUST A DISCUSSION not a world war !! 
pheww..Dude go and get a glass of water

Comment: SO is not a discussion forum, it's a QA site. There's a very obvious difference between `:%Keyword%` and `%:keyword%`. Don't get mad that I pointed out that you are writing randomly. It will only help you, because you'll pay more attention to what you're writing and you won't have to ask help every time you make a typo in your code.

Comment: @Kayaman Its not a typo issue.. before this you also very arrogant.. 
BTW THANK YOU !

Comment: No problem, glad you could fix your error.

Answer (score 1):

Okay With the help of the above comments I am able to run right query

```
@Query("Select pp from ProductPhoto pp join pp.product p where pp.product.id=p.id "
        + "AND p.statusEnabled='true' AND pp.primaryPhoto='true' "
        + "AND (UPPER(p.name) LIKE UPPER(%:keyword%) OR p.description LIKE %:keyword%)")
List<ProductPhoto> sqlLike(@Param("keyword") String Keyword);
```

Comment: what about `p.name ~ :keyword` did you try it?